# Split a string array in different strings in C++ that I have to receive as input parameter from C#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, string

I have function in C# that has to pass a output parameter of string array to C++

These string array needs to be splitted into individual strings .

**C# :-**

```
void calculate(string[] data)
{
            data = new string[5];
            data [0] = keycol[0].ToString() + "|"+ valuecol[0].ToString()+ "|"+Column_name[0];
            data [1] = keycol[1].ToString() + "|" + valuecol[1].ToString()+ "|"+Column_name[1];
            data [2] = keycol[2].ToString() + "|" + valuecol[2].ToString()+ "|"+Column_name[2];
            data [3] = keycol[3].ToString() + "|" + valuecol[3].ToString() + "|" + Column_name[3];           
}
```

**C++:**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
void calculate(char *data[5])
{

vector<string> v;
string s = data[0];
split(s, '|', v);

}

void split(const string& s, char c,
           vector<string>& v) {
   string::size_type i = 0;
   string::size_type j = s.find(c);

   while (j != string::npos) {
      v.push_back(s.substr(i, j-i));
      i = ++j;
      j = s.find(c, j);

      if (j == string::npos)
         v.push_back(s.substr(i, s.length()));
   }
```

The data that I get from C# would be like this :
**cmb1|2|col1,col3**

**cmb2|1|col2**

**cmb3|1|col4**

This is properly stored in the data array in C#.
I face the problem while I send this to C++.
I just get single char while I split the string stored in the data .

I need the result in C++ like this :

```
string c1 = cmb1;
string c2 = 2;
string c3 = col1;
string c4 = col2; 

 string c5= cmb2;
  string c6 =1;
string c7 =col2;
```

Comment: For something simple like this you might want to try using [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: Also, are you *sure* about the argument to `calculate`? Because right now you say that data is an array of pointers to pointers to `char`., not an array of strings (array of pointers to `char`, or `char *data[]`).

Comment: why there is down vote for this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature is wrong... Use

```
void calculate(char **data)
```

or something equivalent, like

```
void calculate(char *data[])
```

The Visual Studio showed me an error caused by that line:

> 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char **' to 'std::basic_string,std::allocator>'

The full code should be something like:

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void calculate(char *data[5])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            vector<string> v;

            if (!data[i])
            {
                continue;
            }

            string s = data[i];
            split(s, '|', v);
        }
    }
}
```

(probably instead of `__declspec(dllexport)` you are using a macro, like `LIBRARY_API` or something else... Continue using it and remove the `__declspec(dllexport)`)

The PInvoke signature C#-side is something like:

```
[DllImport("yourdllname", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern void calculate(string[] data);
```

Comment: I need to assign them as fixed of data[5] so how can I get them @xanatos

Comment: @TechBrkTru You don't need to put the size of the array in the signature. If you want you can write it like `void calculate(char *data[5])` but it doesn't have any effect (other than signaling to the users of the class the "correct" size)

Comment: @TechBrkTru Do the change as I have written. It works. I've tested it in a pinvoke C#->C++. The three syntaxes are equivalent.

Comment: A question all the data is getting stored in string s which is not that i want ,i want them to get stored in different variables @xanatos

Comment: @TechBrkTru The code as written will move the splitted parts to the vector `v`. From there you can do a `string c1 = v[0]; string c2 = v[1]; ...`

Comment: but i always find in v as children not evaluated...@xanatos

Comment: @TechBrkTru Try adding the various `string c1 = ...`. Not always the debugger will show what really is.

Comment: ya doing the same @xanatos